# Boost Program Options Examples

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

In the boost tutorials online for program options : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2891824

It says that the complete code examples can be found at "BOOST_ROOT/libs/program_options/example" directory. I could not figure out where is this. Can anyone help me finding the examples?

Comment: 10 years later... boost options "tutorial" still not fixed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Debian systems, you find it in `/usr/share/doc/libboost-doc/examples/libs/program_options`.
Otherwise, I suggest to download the archive from boost.org and have a look there.

Comment: Got it from the latest boost archive. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On OSX via macports they are in /opt/local/share/doc/boost/libs/ then spattered in there.

Answer (score 22):

The examples are online at
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/program_options/example/

For a different version of boost, change the number in the link.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the examples are here:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/